# Can I use a single Firebase auth account for multiple users?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am building a web app that is a survey, that ~275 people will need to complete. The web app is protected by a single Firebase login, that all users will use.

I just want to check that multiple users can authenticate with the same, single login, even if they're in different geographic locations, and it doesn't trip any security mechanisms. All of the requests will be being made from one location (a Netlify hosted React app)

Can someone confirm to me that this is a strategy that will work? I just want to make sure it doesn't fall over when multiple people try to log in to it.

Thanks
T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Firebase Auth account (email/password) from different browsers/machines in different locations.

(Note that **maybe** you could use [Anonymous authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/anonymous-auth) to implement your requirement. It all depends on the type of security you want to implement).